# using .loc and .isin to look up values in column - Error as list has int and strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data frame - TUCABCP

I have a list called millreflist which contains integers, but now also strings

My objective is to look up the items from millreflist in the dataframe TUCABCP under column 'PO'and then return all the rows into a new dataframe called NEWBCP.

My code was working fine until recently, my millreflist contained a string. Now the issue is when using .loc and .isin when the string is searched up it deletes all the rows and returns the rows with only the string under the 'PO' column.

Below is my code:

```
millreflist = combined['TUCA PO'].tolist()
millreflist = list(dict.fromkeys(millreflist))
df = TUCABCP.loc[TUCABCP['PO'].isin(millreflist)]
df.to_excel("NEWBCP.xlsx", header=True, index=False)
```

For example if I had 5 integers before I would get 5 rows in return - perfect.

Now if I have 5 integers and 1 string, I only get 1 row in return - the string row.

My question is why are all the other rows being discarded and I am only getting the row back with the string.

Comment: Just a thought, have you checked what the list contains before using it to create the new df? The list may only contain the string so that's why it's only returning a string.

Comment: @k753 Hi, yes I have printed the list 13 integers, and 1 string.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Shah. To make it easier for others to help you, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).